# Entity Framework 6 обновление и добавление связанных свойств

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Например, есть 2 сущности, Фильм и Жанр. У жанра свойство Имя уникальное.

И вот я добавляю новый фильм. Выбираю жанр из имеющихся в базе (или несколько жанров). Далее делаю следующее

```
context.Films.Add(film);
context.SaveChanges();
```

По идее в базу должен добавиться новый фильм с выбранными жанрами, но я получаю исключение о том, что нарушена уникальность имени жанра. То есть EF пытается добавить в базу жанров жанры из списка жанров фильма. Почему он не смотрит даже на Id? Ведь в базу уже есть запись с таким Id, почему он просто не оставляет все как есть?

А если делаю так

```
context.Films.AddOrUpdate(film);
context.SaveChanges();
```

То исключений нет, фильм в базу успешно добавляется, но без жанров.

Таблица для связи многие ко многим есть. EF ее видит и понимает (настраивал маппинг), потому что фильмы с уже проставленными жанрами эти самые жанры подтягивают при запросе.

**UPD**

Классы сущностей

```
[DataContract]
public class Film
{
    [DataMember]
    public long FilmId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OriginalName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LocalName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime AddingDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PosterUrl { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int SelfRating { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public float? GlobalRating { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ForeignUrl { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public Film()
    {
        Genres = new List<Genre>();
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Genre
{
    [DataMember]
    public long GenreId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Film> Films { get; set; }
    public Genre()
    {
        Films = new List<Film>();
    }
}
```

Fluent API контекста

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(SQLiteCaseInsensitiveCollation));
    //SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(SqLiteCyrHelper));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Film>().HasMany(g => g.Genres).WithMany(f => f.Films).Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("FilmGenres");
        m.MapLeftKey("FilmId");
        m.MapRightKey("GenreId");
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Film>().Property(f => f.AddingDate).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Film>().Property(f => f.FilmId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().Property(g => g.GenreId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

Comment: Покажи классы и как строил связи..

Comment: @ЕвгенийКидяев, обновил вопрос

Comment: Попробуй так: context.Film.Add(film.Genres.Where(x=>x.GenreId==1).FirstOrDefault()); context.SaveChanges();

Comment: @ЕвгенийКидяев что значит "попробуйте"? Я не понимаю что тут должно произойти. Фактически эта запись означает "Добавить к сету Films первый объект типа Genre у которого GenreId == 1". Как я вообще вместо сущности Film могу подсунуть Genre?

Comment: А откуда Вы берете жанр? Если Вы берете его не из контекста EF, он будет пытаться его создать, это нормально.

Comment: @iRumba вот у вас в настройках m.MapLeftKey("FilmId") m.MapRightKey("GenreId") стоит ключ по которому происходит связь многие ко многим. И вы добавляете к фильму жанр по этому ключу. И показали бы как вы добавляете жанры к фильму.

Comment: @Fynivx, я беру его не из контекста EF. Точнее из контекста, но из другого его экземпляра. Потому что контекст на каждую операцию создается новый. Как быть тогда?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКидяев, жанры я добавляю как то так `film.Genres.Add(new Genre() { ... });`. После этого делаю `context.Films.AddOrUpdate(film);`

Comment: @iRumba, получать его из текущего контекста по ID.

Comment: @iRumba ты должен создать новый жанр добавлять его в таблицу Жанров и потом только добавлять его к фильмам.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКидяев, зачем тогда EF нужен? ) На самом деле вы не правы. С новыми жанрами, как раз, проблем не возникает. Они добавляются нормально. А вот с существующими беда. EF их тоже создать заново пытается. При этом фильмы отлично добавляются и обновляются. мне не приходится подтягивать с базы существующий фильм чтобы его обновить. Я просто передаю измененный фильм контексту через `AddOrUpdate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `AddOrUpdate` не предназначен для добавления связанных сущностей по самой своей природе. Этот метод имеет очень ограниченное применение, и более того - является не частью основы EF, а частью его механизма миграций.

Теперь про метод `Add`. Когда вы применяете этот метод к некоторой сущности - вы автоматически распространяете операцию `Add` на связанные сущности, которые не были добавлены в контекст ранее.

Чтобы EF не пыталась добавить в базу новые жанры, а использовала существующие - она должна знать что эти жанры в базе уже есть. Это знание может быть получено двумя путями. Во-первых, EF знает что такие жанры в базе уже есть, если вы перед этим получили их из базы запросом в том же самом контексте:

```
var g1 = context.Genres.Single(g => g.GenreId = 42);
var film = new Film();
film.Genres.Add(g1);
context.Films.Add(film);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Если же жанр был получен откуда-то еще, то надо его явно присоединить к контексту:

```
var g1 = new Genre { GenreId = 42 };
context.Genres.Attach(g1);

var film = new Film();
film.Genres.Add(g1);
context.Films.Add(film);
context.SaveChanges();
```

---

> Почему он не смотрит даже на Id? Ведь в базу уже есть запись с таким Id, почему он просто не оставляет все как есть?

Потому что EF никогда не использует значение первичного ключа для того чтобы определить что делать с сущностью. Вообще говоря, в базе данных запросто может лежать запись с нулевым Id - а потому на основе Id нельзя понять существует ли такая запись в базе.

Для определения что делать с записью EF использует *состояния* сущностей. Это состояние доступно через конструкцию `context.Entry(...).State`. Всего существует 5 состояний:

- EntityState.Detached (по умолчанию)
- EntityState.Unchanged
- EntityState.Added
- EntityState.Deleted
- EntityState.Modified

При сохранении в БД EF сначала переводит все сущности, связанные с другими, из состояния Detached в состояние Added, после чего добавляет в базу все что находится в состоянии Added, удаляет из базы все что находится в состоянии Deleted, и обновляет атрибуты всего, что находится в состоянии  Modified.

Отсюда имеем третий способ добавить фильмы, но не добавлять жанры:

```
var g1 = new Genre { GenreId = 42 };
var film = new Film();
film.Genres.Add(g1);

context.Entry(film).State = EntityState.Added;
context.Entry(g1).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
context.SaveChanges();
```

PS Иногда предлагается вот такой хак (способ номер 4):

```
context.Films.Add(film);
foreach (var genre in film.Genres) {
    context.Entry(genre).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Почему это работает - написано выше. Но надо понимать, что таким образом вы не сможете добавить в базу фильм и несколько жанров одновременно. Правильнее все же следить за теми сущностями, которые вы используете, и делать над ними правильные операции не откладывая на потом. Потому что в цикле по всем жанрам фильма вы уже не сможете так просто определить какой жанр в базе уже существует, а какой - еще нет.

Comment: Если сущность имеет кучу связей, например, фильм имеет коллекцию жанров, коллекцию актеров, какие-то связанные фильмы или серии, как быть? Каждый раз нужно пробегаться по всем этим сущностям и приаттачивать их к контексту? Универсальностью, увы, не пахнет. Есть ли универсальные способы? Все бы это хорошо работало "из коробки", если контекст всегда один и тот же, но долгоживущий контекст не рекомендуется и он всегда свежесозданный.

Comment: @Андрей вам в любом случае нужен отдельный кусок кода для обработки каждого вида связанных сущностей. Надо лишь добавить туда правильную работу с контекстом.

Comment: @Андрей есть еще одно хорошее универсальное правило: просто не трогать те связи, которые не менялись.

Comment: Ну смотрите, я создаю экземпляр фильма и не хочу его сразу сохранять в базу, потому что я хочу иметь возможность в любой момент времени отказаться от затеи и ничего не сохранять. Добавляю к этому фильму теперь жанры, актеров и прочих. Теперь хочу всё это сохранить в БД. Как быть? Получается метод добавления фильмов сильно связан с с самим классом фильма и если я буду менять класс фильма, добавлять новые связи или т.п, то придется менять и код сохранения фильма?

Comment: @Андрей если вы пишите простое приложение - то самым простым выходом будет создавать один контекст на все время редактирования фильма.

Comment: @Андрей в многозвенных архитектурах вам нужно будет продумать общий механизм сохранения состояния сущности и списка измененных сущностей

Answer (score 0):

Создаем фильм и добавляем существующий жанр.

```
Film film=new Film();
film.Genres.Add(context.Genres.Where(x=>x.GenreId==1).FirstOrDefault());
context.Films.Add(film);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Не работает. Оно вообще должно работать и без таких вот заморочей. Фильмы же нормально добавляются и обновляются, так почему с жанрами такая проблема?