# Entity Framework некорректно обновляется запись

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Уже задавал вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635932/entity-framework-6-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2). Он до сих пор актуален.

Короче имеем фильмы и жанры со связью многие ко многим. Сейчас проблема немного отличается и я копнул чуть глубже.

Я пока не буду описывать логику получения результата. Скажу, что я хотел сделать и покажу результат. Я добавил в уже существующий фильм существующий жанр. Вот данные с контекста перед сохранением.

[image: Скрин контрольных значений]

Как видно из скрина, обновленный фильм помечен как `Modified`. Жанр помечен как `Unchanged`. Жанр, который хранится в `film.Genres` есть тот же самый объект, что и в контексте в локальных значениях жанров. Но при сохранении жанр не добавляется к фильму, хотя все остальные данные (название, описание и тд) успешно сохраняются. Я не могу понять почему.

Comment: Вы используете *навигационные свойства* для работы со связанными сущностями?

Comment: @Bald да. Навигационные свойства настроены нормально. По крайней мере запросы на выборку работают нормально. Новый фильм добавляется нормально, как с существующими в базе жанрами так и с новыми. Но вот существующий фильм чего-то не хочет обновлять жанры

Comment: т.е. существующий жанр к фильму Вы добавляете так: `film.Genres.Add(genre);` так? и после `context.SaveChanges()` ? и это не работает?

Comment: @Bald, там не все так просто. Вот то что вы привели имеет ряд нюансов. Например, откуда взялся объект `film`? В моем случае он просто создается и наполняется данными. Контекста в этот момент вообще не существует, контекст создается позже. Далее в базе ищется переданный для обновления или изменения фильм. если он есть, то текущий объект помечается как `Modified`, иначе как `Added`. Далее таким же образом просматриваются все жанры фильмов. А если я просто делаю context.Films.AddOrUpdate(film) то все работает очень непредсказуемо

Comment: добавьте в вопрос информации откуда берется *film, genre*

Comment: @Bald, не совсем понял что именно вы от меня хотите. `film` просто где то создается. Где то за пределами контекста. Вообще за пределами проекта DataLayer. Возможно, я смогу понять, если вы объясните какое это имеет значение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54923/discussion-between-bald-and-irumba).

Comment: не знаю актуально или нет, но вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/658644/179270).