# Как обновить данные при связи многие ко многим?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть следующая доменная модель:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Cource> Cources {get;set;}

    public Student()
    {
        this.Cources = new HashSet<Cource>();
    }
}

public class Cource
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get;set;}

    public Cource()
    {    
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();    
    }    
}
```

Как мне изменить(удалить) связь между *студентом* и *курсом*, т.е. добавить студенту новый курс, удалить существующий?

Answer (score 1):

Свой ответ я буду строить исходя из того что фактическое редактирование происходит на *отсоединенной* записи, либо же для в `gui` используются `view model`, `dto` объекты.

Для того что бы [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) вас понял необходимо сделать следующее

1. Присоединить к контексту существующую запись, например так: `var student = _context.Students.Attach(new Student {Id = model.Id});`
2. Загрузить связанные курсы при помощи навигационного свойства: `context.Entry(student).Collection(x=>x.Cources).Load();`
3. Необходимо понять какие курсы необходимо добавить а какие удалить.

   3.1. `var deletedCources = student.Cources.Except(model.Cources, cource=>cource.Id);`

   3.2. `var addedCources = model.Cources.Except(student.Cources, cource=>cource.Id);`
4. Затем соответственно необходимо удалить/добавить курсы студенту: `deletedCources.ForEach(cource=>student.Cources.Remove(cource));` , `addedCources.ForEach(cource=>student.Cources.Add(cource));`
5. В заключении говорим *ef* что объект студент был изменен и сохраняем: `_context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;` `_context.SaveChanges();`

---

```
public void EditStudent(StudentViewModel model)
{
    using(var _context = new DefaultContext())
    {
        var student = _context.Students.Attach(new Student {Id = model.Id});

        _context.Entry(student).Collection(x=>x.Cources).Load();

        var deletedCources = student.Cources.Except(model.Cources, Cource=>cource.Id);
        var addedCources = model.Cources.Except(student.Cources, cource=>cource.Id);

        deletedCources.ForEach(cource=>student.Cources.Remove(cource));
        addedCources.ForEach(cource=>student.Cources.Add(cource));

        _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Перегруженная версия метода `Except()` используемая в примере

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items,
                                             IEnumerable<T> other,
                                             Func<T, TKey> getKey)
{
    return from item in items
           join otherItem in other on getKey(item) equals getKey(otherItem) into tempItems
           where !tempItems.Any()
           select item;

}
```

адаптация [статьи](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-many-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: Зачем так сложно, с `.DefaultIfEmpty()` и прочим? `where tempItems.Count() == 0` и никакой магии.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я взял код из вот этой [статьи](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-many-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx).

Comment: Это же не повод писать ерунду? :-) Та статья, по всей видимости, была написана человеком, который хорошо знает SQL и плохо знает LINQ...

Comment: @PavelMayorov <strike>тогда наверно возможно вместо `Count()` использовать `Any()`. счас проверю и отредактирую.</strike> сначала написал, потом увидел вашу правку :)